# Cannot access device (not in user datastore)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 to target Windows CE 5.0 and 6.0 devices. Up until yesterday I was deploying to a variety of devices without issue. However, this morning I was unable to deploy to one of my devices.

In Visual Studio, after selecting Tools > Options > Device Tools > Devices, my devices are all listed correctly. I can view the properties of all my devices (and the `Delete` button is enabled for all of them)...except the device I am now having trouble with. When I select this device, `Delete` is disabled selecting `Properties` shows this error:

```
Error retrieving information from user datastore. Property not found.
```

There have been no changes to either my system or Visual Studio that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with this for some time, I found the following rather drastic solution:

- Load the properties of one of the devices that is working and note down the (working) settings
- Exit Visual Studio and all other VS tools such as `Remote Registry Viewer`
- Navigate to `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\corecon` and rename the folder `1.0` to `1.0_backup`
- Reload the project in Visual Studio. You will see a variety of errors about a device listed as not being available in the datastore. Just keep going until all errors are acknowledged.
- Exit Visual Studio
- Return to the path mentioned above and rename the folder `1.0_backup` to `1.0`
- Reload the project in Visual Studio. You will notice that all your devices have been lost.
- In Tools > Options > Device Tools > Devices copy the default `Windows CE 5.0 Device` and enter the properties noted in the first item in this list
- Repeat for any other device you need to deploy to (typically to enter the IP address for the device)
- You can now deploy to devices as normal

Hope that helps anyone who has a similar problem.

Comment: Note: On 64-bit Windows 10, the path is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\corecon`

Comment: The error may be `The operation could not be completed. The device is not connected.`. In this case, you probably have one or more missing files in your project. Carefully review the `Output` window of Visual Studio and look for `Error deploying file` message(s).